# angularjs localstorage against page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am doing a few steps form with angularjs. There is always possibility that user hit F5 button, and refreshes the page. Then all data collected with angular will be deleted. I would like to prevent myself against that possibility.

I thought about using Local Storage and angular library for that, but so far I'm not convinced yet that it is proper path to deal with my problem. Is my thinking correct, or there is better idea to solve that?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What exactly do you want the user to prevent from? You cannot disable or prevent the page refresh. What you coud do is with the help of appchache (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) and local-storage let the browser load the data directly from the cache instead of making a new request.
But you don't need AngularJS for that and it does not help you especially for this use case...

Comment: depends on the problem you are trying to avoid, for me i add the crucial details to the URL and use the details to rebuild the page from the url

Comment: @DanEEStar, you are right, as I read my question again it might be unclear. I want my user to keep data from previous, or even current form step even if they refresh page.
I know I can also send request to backend after filling every field, but it would be huge number of requests, so I think it is also not so good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chek out http://sisyphus-js.herokuapp.com/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&basic_form_country=USA&basic_form_name=hihi~&button=#advanced-sample
This is a library that persist your form's data in a browser's Local Storage. It is very easy to use, you have the option to save all the input field and you will be able to retrieve it even from other page.